# Adding moderators for comment plugin using appid

Tags: html, facebook, plugins, facebook-opengraph, facebook-comments

i've recently added fb comment plugin into my tumblr site but i can't seem to link my comment boxes to my appid.

heres what i've done so far.

i added this under the  section of my site

```
`<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=271024526292744";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>`
```

also, i've added this under the  section of my site

```
`<meta property="fb:app_id" content="271024526292744"/>`
```

i then added this on pages of my site for the comment box to appear

```
`<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://theg-times.tumblr.com/galactosemia/introduction" data-num-posts="10" data-width="470"></div>`
```

basically, the comment box works like normal with the exception that the comments entered does not show up under my comment moderation tool and i am unable to moderate the comments made by others depite myself being the app developer AND comment moderator. may i know where i might have gone wrong?

Thanks,
Ernest

Comment: You need to pass your page URL to [Debug Tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to remove cached version which was without `fb:app_id` tag. If it's still not working file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the url you specified in the code is identical to the url in the address bar of the page.